# Why don't we have Algorithms.SE?

Tags: discussion, site-proposal

There should be Algorithms.stackexchange.com so that programmers can discuss algorithm problems apart from other stuff.
I mean for a separate space, because there are so many networks of Stack Exchange like CSTheory, Area 51 and even Programmers.SE.

I can say if there is Programmers.SE separately for programmers, then there should be Algorithms.SE, otherwise algorithm sort of stuff is not justified on Stack Exchange network.

It's a big thing. Algorithms are everywhere, then why not Algorithms.SE?

Comment: Also, questions about algorithms are on topic for Stack Overflow (and apparently also on Programmers, and to some extent, Math.SE). I don't see why there should be yet another site for this. But if you want, you can create a proposal on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) and see if you can get that going.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ Oooohhhhh...don't forget [Computational Science](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/), now in beta.

Answer (score 9):

What sort of algorithm questions do you have in mind that don't already have a home on the network?

- Conceptual algorithm questions and questions about algorithm design are on-topic on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).
- Problems with implementing specific algorithms are on-topic on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).
- Research-level algorithm questions are on-topic on [Theoretical Computer Science](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com).

You could open a proposal on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) for an Algorithms Stack Exchange site, but I imagine it'd get closed as a duplicate of the above.

Comment: Math.SE is also somewhat receptive to algorithm questions.

Comment: how many complex algorithms people use every day when they check their e-mail or listen to music on their computers ?

Comment: @Abhinav Don't forget though, stack exchange isn't for discussion of topics. It's for answering questions to solve problems. So while it might be interesting to discuss all the different algorithms we encounter in our daily lives, how often are we presented with a problem to solve related to those algorithms? Is it often enough to support its own community?

Comment: @AbhinavPandey That sounds like a question best asked on another site. Quora and Reddit come to mind. As glowcoder points out, Stack Exchange sites aim to solve problems rather than just satisfy curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

You mention Area 51. You should know that Area 51 is the place to be asking this question, by creating a site proposal for Algorithms as separate from SO/Programmers/Math.SE. If you can describe *why* algorithms should be made into a separate site, please do so in [discuss.area51](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com).

Just to let you know though, algorithms *are* on-topic at Stack Overflow and other sites as mentioned in Anna's answer, and people before you have wanted to start a separate algorithms site, but [the proposal was deleted](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2271/data-structure-algorithms-seems-like-a-dupe-to-me).