# Where can I ask "How to improve my application" questions?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, stack-exchange, off-topic

I coded an event manager in C++ and it works fine. For educational purpose, I would like to improve it. But I don't know what the next step could be.

Asking this question on Stack Overflow felt unsuitable, so I decided to discard my question draft there and ask here on Meta before.

Is there a Stack Exchange site for this kind of questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the code-quality part you could go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

If you want  a discussion about features etc, maybe programmers?

If you have a method/algorithm for event-handling you wish to discuss, see the answer on this question for a list of locations: [why not algorithms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116511/why-not-algorithms)

> - Conceptual algorithm questions and questions about algorithm design are on-topic on Programmers.
> - Problems with implementing specific algorithms are on-topic on Stack Overflow.
> - Research-level algorithm questions are on-topic on Theoretical Computer Science.

Comment: Thanks. My question would be "concept-quality", not quite code-quality or feature discussion.

Comment: Well, if you have, for instance, a certain algorithm you wish to discuss, there are several options, see some outlines for isntance here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116511/why-not-algorithms

Comment: Whiteboard/concept questions are best suited for programmers, but but seeing as you don't have an account there, please check out their faq/help center to make sure your question is on topic.

Comment: Thanks, I'll register on Programmers.

Comment: thanks i have been wondering for the same answer from quite a while